# Object allocation when using RxJava in 'high traffic' code?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I just started exploring RxJava recently and applied it to a small part of my project. It turns out this part is small but one with 'high traffic': it gets called a lot by other components. An example would be a network client that gets called repeatedly to fetch remote data, applies a few transformations to the response, then fires callback event. Let's just say these transformations are lightweight so I can do it on main thread:

```
restService.getData() // retrofit interface that returns Observable<T>
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .map(data -> someMapping(data))
    .map(data -> someOtherMapping(data))
    .subscribe(this::fireResponseCallback, this::fireErrorCallback)
```

Now the same could be done without RxJava:

```
restService.getData() // retrofit interface that returns Call<T>
    .enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
            T data = response.body();
            data = someMapping(data);
            data = someOtherMapping(data);
            fireResponseCallback(data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
            fireErrorCallback(t);
        }
    });
```

What I observe with RxJava is that it creates a lot of more objects in memory. For the example above, each execution go through 4 lambda expressions, each makes 1 instantiation of anonymous class (`Func1<>` or `Action1<>`). Without RxJava, you only have 1 instantiation of anonymous class (`Callback<T>`). This difference widens quickly as the same logic gets triggered multiple times. I wonder if this is something that I should be mindful about when using RxJava? If yes then what would be good practices to keep the number of objects small?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, RxJava 1.x allocates more objects than theoretically needed for a reactive sequence (due to some design choices) but it shouldn't be that drastic. It's allocation rate becomes apparent for synchronous local sequences but rarely for network-based sequences.

If your Action and Func lambdas are pure, you can pre-allocate them in member fields and just reuse their references in the lambdas. In addition, if `restService.getData()` is consumable multiple times, you can save the entire chain into a field and just call `subscribe` whenever needed.

```
class DataAccess {
    final RestService restService;

    final Observable<T> call = restService.getData()
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .map(data -> someMapping(data))
        .map(data -> someOtherMapping(data));

    final Action1<T> consumer = this::fireResponseCallback;

    final Action1<Throwable> errorHandler = this::fireErrorCallback;

    DataAccess(RestService restService) {
        this.restService = restService;
    }

    void doDataAccess() {
        call.subscribe(consumer, errorHandler);
    }
}
```